# JSonarray to Arraylist and Arraylist in ListAdapter doesn't work. (In Android)

Tags: android, json, listview, arraylist, android-arrayadapter

I've got a little problem, and i don't see it.

I retrieve Json data (the `JSONArray`) and i wanted to make a `List` of all the names in the `JSONArray`, something like this.

```
List list = new ArrayList<String>();
for(int i=0;i < data.length();i++){ 
    list.add(data.getJSONObject(i).getString("names").toString());
}
```

And i wanted to take this list in an `ListView' so i did this :

```
ArrayList<String> test = history_share.list;
names_list = (String[]) test.toArray();
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, 
    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, names_list);
setListAdapter(adapter);
```

(history_share is one of the method i created to take json data from an api .
Eclipse doesn't see any error, and me neither.

Can somebody help me please ?

Comment: What isn't working? What error messages are you getting?

Comment: i've got nothing that's the problem, and when i lauch the android application it makes a : "the application has stop unexpectedly" thing.

Comment: @Tsunaue: There has to be a logcat output for this exception.

Comment: the first error is a java.lang.runtimeexeption (i don't know how to copy the logcat)

Answer (score 0):

Why do your methods have underscores in their names? Methods by convention begin with a lowercase letter. For example `myMethod()`. Class names begin with uppercase letters like `MyClass`. You should stick to that.

Also `history_share` is not a method the way you posted your code plus you won't be able to retrieve anything from a method by calling it that way.

A getter method just returns the defined member. I'm very surprised that Eclipse doesn't highlight that. Are you sure error checking is turned on?

**Update:** Naming your classes like already existing classes is generally a very bad idea and it gets even worse if you plan to use the original class somewhere or any class deriving that class. In the original [Connection](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/sql/Connection.html) class I cant spot any static member called list which leads to the assumption that you've created your own Connection class. This doesn't have to be the problem here but it may raise problems in the future if you continue to do that.

Comment: yes, and i've got two classes : Main.java and Connection.java , i created history_share like this : Connection history_share = new Connection(url); history_share is an object (sorry for the miscommunication)

Comment: hmm yep i didn't know that there was a Connection class, but for the others features my connection class works fine. It's just the list the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i=0;i < data.length();i++){ 
    list.add(data.getJSONObject(i).getString("names").toString());
}


.getString("names") returns String, remove .toString()
```

Also,

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, 
    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, names_list);
```

replace with

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, 
    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, names_list);
```

Answer (score 0):

You try this using `ArrayList` with `Hashmap`:

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> comunitylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

String url =_url + _uid + uid;

JSONParstring jParser = new JSONParstring();

// getting JSON string from URL
String json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url,apikey);

Log.e("kPN", json);
try
{
    JSONObject jobj = new JSONObject(json);
    Log.e("kPN", json.toString());
    System.out.print(json);
    JSONArray comarray = jobj.getJSONArray(TAG_COMMU);

    for(int i = 0; i <= comarray.length(); i++){
        JSONObject c = comarray.getJSONObject(i);
        Log.w("obj", c.toString());
        JSONObject d = c.getJSONObject(TAG_PERSON);
        Log.w("obj", d.toString());
        String name =d.getString(TAG_NAME);
        Log.w("name", name);

        String nick =d.getString(TAG_NICK);
        String home = d.getString(TAG_HOME);
        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        map.put(TAG_NAME, name);
        map.put(TAG_NICK, nick);
    }
}
catch (JSONException ie)
{

}

list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
adapter=new Lazycommunity(this,listz);

list.setAdapter(adapter);

list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                            int position, long id) {

        //Having Trouble with this line, how to retrieve value???
        HashMap<String, String> map2 = (HashMap<String, String>) list.getAdapter().getItem(position);

        Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Communityprofile.class);
        in.putExtra(TAG_NAME, map2.get(TAG_NAME));
        in.putExtra(TAG_IMG, map2.get(TAG_IMG));

        startActivity(in);
    }
});
```

Comment: You should remove the `Log` calls because they don't contribute to your answer.